# Getting national visa after getting Work permit in Germany

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, working-visas, work-permit

I have received the work permit approval from embassy. Below is the message

> We have received the Approval from Embassy/Immigration Authorities for your application

Also i have this message.

> Please proceed with work permit visa stamping process and make sure that it is completed within 6 months from the date of approval.

Now
1) if i missed to do the visa stamping within 6 months what will happen? Will my work permit get cancelled?

2) Should i apply National Visas?

3) Am i eligible to apply Schengen-Visas now? Because i'm not getting any appointment for National visas in next 3 months. But i have to visit the client urgently

Comment: As in your last question, it's not entirely clear which documents you're talking about. What type of "work permit" do you have?

Comment: Hi @ChrisH .I have `Work Permit Processing - Long Term visa for Germany`

Comment: "Work Permit Processing - Long Term visa for Germany" doesn't name a type of visa or permit. If you're coming to work in Germany as a non-EU citizen, you'll need one of several different types of residence permit which allow you to work. You can see the various types [here](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/Arbeiten/BuergerDrittstaat/buerger-drittstaat-node.html), it might be hard to provide firm answers without knowing exactly what type you have. If you're planning to move long term, your question might be a better fit at [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: all that said, for the final part of your question, whether you can apply for a Schengen visa: anything you can reasonably describe as a German work permit is in fact a residence title, if you hold one there is no need to get a Schengen visa.